# How to Convert this string to upper case by using interrupt?

Tags: assembly, emu8086

I written the below code. When I emulate it in emu8086 just shows me the letters in lower case on the screen.

I want convert these characters to upper case by using another interrupt and function. How can it be done?

```
       LEA BX, MSG
       MOV AH, 2
       MOV CX, 26

  DON: MOV DL, [BX]                                                        
       INT 21H
       INC BX
       LOOP DON
       RET

       MSG DB 'study of assembly language'
```

Comment: Why would you assume that there is a DOS or BIOS function that converts strings to upper-case? Back in the old days, the whole world was assumed to be ASCII, so case conversion was a brain-dead simple process. It didn't need to be an API.

Comment: There's a new answer to your question, check it out!

Answer (score 1):

There's **none** emu8086 interrupt providing service of lowercase to uppercase conversion.

Convert it on your own - after doing `mov dl,[bx]` you have character value in `dl` before using "Display Output" function of `int 21h`. So between those two you can modify the value of character.

Study something about [ASCII encoding](http://www.tntbasic.com/learn/help/guides/asciicodesexplained.htm) to see what number is in `dl`, and what DOS will show on screen of it. Then think which numbers you want to manipulate and in what way. Turning lowercase ASCII into uppercase ASCII letter may take single `and` instruction, if you are safe to assume only letters are going through, but you may want to preserve "space" as "space", or even preserving numbers and other non-letter characters.

Like let's say you want to change values from 4 to 7 to values [10, 11, 8, 9] , and you want to keep other intact:

```
  ; convert DL: values [4, 5, 6, 7] -> [10, 11, 8, 9]
  ; keep other values intact
    cmp dl,4
    jb  keepIntact  ; when DL < 4, jump (jb = jump below)
    cmp dl,7
    ja  keepIntact  ; when DL > 7, jump (ja = jump above)
    xor dl,14       ; do magic (calculates new value)
    ; continue with the same code as values 0-4 and 8-255
keepIntact:
  ; here DL contains patched/intact value, as wanted
```

> One way to convert lowercase ASCII letter into uppercase is to do "`and dl,0DFh`" .. it will turn values 97-122 into 65-90 (and "damage" various others ... and keep some, like 65-90 will stay intact, so uppercase letters on input will be not modified by this). To understand how this work, look at value `122` (`'a'`) in binary, and then look at binary of `0DFh`, and do your math.

---

About [link](http://lateblt.tripod.com/asm.htm) from comment, there's paragraph *"Turn on all keyboard "lock"s"* with code (I added my comments after ";#"):

```
;Move F0h to 40:17
  ;# this is trying to explain what code below does
  ;# which is: store word value 0x00F0 at absolute
  ;# physical memory address 0040:0017

MOV DS,40h
MOV BX,17h   ;# ds:bx points to 0040:0017
MOV AX,0F0h
MOV [BX], AX ;# store 0x00F0 at [ds:bx]

  ;# this just terminates DOS program, not related to "locks"
mov ah,004C  ;terminate program
int 21h
```

I found more detailed description of BIOS and keyboard in this [PDF](http://www.plantation-productions.com/Webster/www.artofasm.com/DOS/pdf/ch20.pdf) (looks to be published by author, legal for personal electronic usage, not to be printed (buy paper hard-copy for printed version)).

Now I will try to explain a bit more, what is that piece of code about, but generally if you didn't get it from your book, then I'm afraid my short explanation may be even worse.

In 16bit mode the keyboard is handled by BIOS interrupt. "Interrupt" in this case means the code of handler, which is `int 9`, and it is executed by the microcontroller receiving input from keyboard device, converting it into scancode and putting that value at 60h I/O port. This `int 9` handler then does conversion from scan code into ASCII (plus conversions according to current state ctrl/shift/caps lock/num lock/...) and makes it available for other programs reading keyboard through BIOS or DOS interrupts. Putting 0F0h into memory location at 0040:0017 will affect the `int 9` handler to think the "caps lock" was set ON by the user, so any next letter keyboard input from user will be uppercase (unless the user holds also shift when typing).

Generally this is so internal to old DOS times, that you shouldn't pay attention to this, it's of zero use in the world of MS-Windows/linux. Emu8086 maybe does partly emulate this functionality, but I wouldn't bet on it, it's mostly emulating `int 10h` / `int 21h` services, and only few of them, I don't think it goes to such length that it will also emulate whole internal functionality of `int 9h` checking values at virtual 0040:0017. The `dosbox` 16bit PC emulator *does* that (to make many old DOS software to work correctly).

But once again, this affects state of keyboard (and I mean the old ones, either original IBM PC keyboard, or more "modern" PS/2 keyboard. Today many keyboard are connected through USB, handled in completely different way and needs different BIOS handler to make them work).

It doesn't convert any string. Which makes me wonder what are you actually asking about.

Comment: the book I study says there is an interrupt for caps lock but I couldn't use it and there is an information about it here: http://lateblt.tripod.com/asm.htm which I couldn't understand in the same way. If you locate the link and search --Turn on all keyboard "lock"s-- title you can see.

Comment: @NoWeDoR I'm not even sure where to start, as you mix together three different things... 1) your question title is "how to convert string". Your book and your link doesn't relate to that at all. 2) link is about switching ON/OFF LEDs on keyboard (LED = Light Emitting Diode), the classic IBM PC keyboard had three lights on top right corner of keyboard, reporting about current status of caps lock/num lock/scroll lock. You can switch those lights in any way you wish under DOS. I'm not sure what it will do in some emulator, probably nothing. 3) book sounds like doing your own keyboard interrupt.

Comment: @NoWeDoR hmm.. checking that link source code again, it's not about LEDs probably, but about really turning on the actual "lock" of the DOS keyboard handler routine... I will try to decide which one it is, and add to answer .. Either way it will not convert your string.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an interrupt, you only need to check if DL is in the range 'a'..'z' before displaying it :

```
       LEA BX, MSG
       MOV AH, 2
       MOV CX, 26

  DON: MOV DL, [BX]                                                        
       cmp dl, 'a'
       jb  display   ;◄■■ IF DL < 'a' (JB=JUMP IF BELOW).
       cmp dl, 'z'
       ja  display   ;◄■■ IF DL > 'z' (JA=JUMP IF ABOVE).
       sub dl, 32    ;◄■■ CONVERT LOWERCASE TO UPPERCASE ('a'=97, 'A'=65).
  display:
       INT 21H
       INC BX
       LOOP DON
       RET
```